# Creating C# tracking and Matching script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently playing around and testing Unity in order to develop a game and I had a general question about C# scripting. Is it possible to create a script that keeps track of the pixel position of a moving game object you created and stores it in a variable?

I haven't tried anything yet. I'm wondering if there are already classes that deal with this in the Unity or C# libraries and if so where or how I can find it.

Comment: You can do anything in c# provided you have the knowledge, my approach to it would be to, every time it gets updated you dump it into a text file/database, depending on the time we re talking you could dump it into memory but i would advise against it.

Answer (score 3):

The `Camera` class handles that in a straight-forward manner: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

> Transforms position from world space into screen space.
>
> Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is
>   (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in
>   world units from the camera.

Where and how you store that information is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

### Code for Tracking position

public GameObject Cube;

void Update () {

```
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    Debug.Log(Cube.transform.position); 

}
```